# UIToolbar left and right paddings are initially negative

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, uitoolbar

I'm struggling with UIToolbar's strange behaviour in iOS7+ iPhone application.

Here's how I created it:

```
//toolbar
self.bottomToolbar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height-44.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0)];
self.bottomToolbar.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
[MKUIHelper toolbar:self.bottomToolbar setBarStyle:MKBarStyleWhite];
self.bottomToolbar.items=@[];
[self.view addSubview:self.bottomToolbar];
```

When I need to update it I'm calling (actually updating only one of its items but this does not matter):

```
-(void)updateToolbar
{
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonDidPress:)];
    doneBarButtonItem.tintColor=MK_Color_Green;
    UIBarButtonItem *clearBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(clearButtonDidPress:)];
    clearBarButtonItem.tintColor=MK_Color_Pink;
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceBetweenBackAndQuantity=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceBetweenQuantityAndClear=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];        

    UIBarButtonItem *quantityItem=[self quantityBarButtonItem];
    self.bottomToolbar.items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneBarButtonItem, spaceBetweenBackAndQuantity, quantityItem, spaceBetweenQuantityAndClear, clearBarButtonItem, nil];

    [self.rootViewController reloadToolbar];
}
```

Both `UIBarButtonItem` objects that was created using `initWithTitle:..` have negative left and right paddings somehow. It can be roughly fixed by adding additional fixed space type UIBarButtonItems to both sides of the items array. In other words: compensate strange initial left and right paddings with fixed space type UIBarButtonItems.

Help me someone, please. What causes such strange effect? How can I get rid of this strange padding?

Here's how it looks like:

[image: strange initial toolbar negative padding]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of what this issue looks like?

Comment: Edited my question with toolbar picture

Comment: I'm not sure if the `autoresizingMask` has anything to do with your problem, but try removing that line and see what happens. Also, are you using autolayout?

Comment: view debugging might help you to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: not using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of barButtons to correct width, you may be able to work around this.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title action:(SEL)action {

    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:action] autorelease];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitle:title forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    CGSize size = button.bounds.size;

    [barButtonItem setWidth:size.width];

    return barButtonItem;
}
```